# Firebase async error handling not catching error with Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to perform error handling for my Firebase API calls using asynchronous methods.

```
do {
  let authUser = try await Auth.auth().signInAnonymously()
  self.user = authUser.user
} catch {
  // Not printing error when there is an auth error??
  print(error)
}
```

Errors are not being caught when they are thrown. Anyone have experience using asynchronous error handing with Firebase?

Comment: You are signing in anonymously, what error do you expect?

Comment: @loremipsum Network error... This is just an example. 
Im also reading/writing data with asynchronous methods.

Comment: What error do you expect to get?

Comment: Try something like `print("\n\t\(error)")` and look for the stop sign in the console. If you truly don't have network access you should see it.

Comment: Im seeing this in the console 
`Task <B45B0618-032D-4299-802F-7AF14455EC10>.<9> finished with error [-1009] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1009 "The Internet connection appears to be offline."`
But im not able to catch it. im not seeing my print statements.

Comment: If that was after the stop sign then that is the print statement

Comment: The stop sign is not appearing